# Convert Char* Variable To uint32_t in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I've got an Sqlite database and i'm reading values back out using this loop:

```
int i;

for(i=0; i<argc; i++) // [0] = IP, [1] = seq, [2] = count
{
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
}

if (atoi(argv[2]) > stealthBeta)
{
    confirmSEQ((uint32_t)argv[1]);
}
```

The value in `argv[1]` is stored as an `UNSIGNED INT` in the database and is being written out to the console properly but when I call the function I'm getting the wrong number.

I've tried casting it but it's not exactly working. What's the proper way to get it from the `char*` to `uint32_t`?

Comment: you can't cast this, you need to convert it, for example using `atoi` like you do in your if statement.

Comment: Oh, that was easy o.o - put it as an answer i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `atoi()` for conversion to `int`.

Use `(unsigned)atoi()` for conversion to `unsigned`.

For example, in your case:

```
if (atoi(argv[2]) > stealthBeta)
{
    confirmSEQ((uint32_t)atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to the number it represents, use `strtol()` or `strtoul()` from `<stdlib.h>`.  `strtoul()` parses an `unsigned long`, guaranteed to be at least 32 bit wide.  Passing `0` as the `base` parameter allows conversion of hexadecimal representation prefixed with `0x`.  Values prefixed with just `0` will be parsed as octal, otherwise parsing is done in decimal.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

if (strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0) > stealthBeta) {
    confirmSEQ((uint32_t)strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0));
}
```